# Check if model column exists before saving in database

Tags: magento-1.9, model, best-practice

I want to insert a column into my db table, but only if it does not exist, yet.
So I thought I'd check if the model with the specified email exists, and if not I perform `save()` method.

Here is what I do:

```
$customerModel = Mage::getModel('custom/customerobject');
$loadedModel = $customerModel->load($RequestParams['email'],'email'); 
$customerIsUnique = empty($loadedModel->getData('email'));

if($customerIsUnique)
{
    // Do stuff
 }
```

Is this the common way how it's done in magento or is there a better way, like
`$customerModel->saveOnlyIfItDoesNotExistOrAnyOtherAwesomeMethod()` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you check it like that..

```
$customerModel=Mage::getModel("custom/customerobject")->getCollection()
                          ->addFieldToFilter('email', array('eq' => $RequestParams['email']));
if(count($customerModel)==1)
    {  
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Email Already Registered');

          $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                    return;
    }else { // do your code here }
```

Comment: thanks :)
I implemented my own error object like 

 Mage::getSingleton('custom/statusobject')->setMessage('foo'); but after the redirect this is gone
maybe you can also give me a hint or should I open new question?

Comment: this is global message built in module for diplaying message i think you use that or otherwise you have to use core session. to display.